# Can the diffraction/interference pattern behind the slit (double slit) be calculated with Feynman path integrals (QED)?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, double-slit-experiment, path-integral, interference, diffraction

I often see Feynman path integrals explained by a graphic which shows the slit and then the electron goes all possible ways behind the slit.

Ok that is nice to understand the Feynman path integral, but it just the solution for one electron.

So can we calculate the entire diffraction/interference pattern on the screen with Feynman path integrals? For example, if the outcome of the slit is the sinc Function.

How to calculate the sinc() function (diffraction pattern on the screen) with Feynman path integral?

Comment: Yes, the entire diffraction pattern can be calculated with a path integral. A google search gets you this http://arxiv.org/pdf/1110.2346.pdf in second place. Insufficient effort? Having said that, direct path integral calculations are tedious and only of limited usefulness for these kinds of problems.

Comment: See also [Young's Double Slit Experiment in Quantum Field Theory](http://arxiv.org/abs/1103.0100)

Comment: great. as stated in the abstract, the question really is why not teaching the slit experiment this way at high-school?? I think, I will ask this academic question the community again.

Comment: High-school students barely know how to ingrate, so path integrals seems unreasonable.